# Jquery selector: jquery function which alters the style of the `<li>` containing the 'quit' link

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given following html code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="somelink">
      <span class='someIconCss'></span>
      <span>home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  [possibly some more <li></li>]
  <li>
    <a href="somelink">
      <span class='someIconCss'></span>
      <span>quit</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  [possibly some more <li></li>]
</ul>
```

I would like to have a jquery function which alters the style of the `<li>` containing the 'quit' link.
For now, I have the following:

```
jQuery("li > a > span > span:contains('quit')").parent().parent().parent().attr("style", "float:right");
```

but I'm pretty sure there is a better way.
Problem is that `jQuery("li > a > span > span:contains('quit')")` returns the span element in stead of the `<li>`

Most readable answer wins...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`.has()`**](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('li').has('span:contains("quit")')
```

or go the other way and use [**`.closest()`**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('span:contains("quit")').closest('li')
// maybe with `$('ul span:contains("quit")')` if you have another span with
// `quit` somewhere in the page. Even better: Give your menu an id!
```

More understandable might also be `a:contains("quit")`, as it is clearer that you mean the quit *link*...

Answer (score 3):

If you know the word 'quit' can't appear anywhere else:

```
jQuery('li:contains("quit")')
```

since `contains` checks *all* descendants, not just children.

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/r8yBb/

Comment: +1 for the jsfiddle example, with which I could test all the others :)

Comment: I took the answer of Felix, because it is a bit of a risk to assume that 'quit' can't appear anywhere else...

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
jQuery('li:has(span:contains("quit"))').css('float', 'right');
```

Note that I've also used the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) method for setting the style.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original code:

```
jQuery("li > a > span > span:contains('quit')").closest("li")
```

will give you the containing `<li>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
$('li:contains("quit")').css("float", "right");
```